# Send mail to Gmail where message is marked as Priority in the user's inbox

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

How can I send an email to a Gmail account where the message will be flagged or marked as Priority, or Important, in the user's inbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t control if a message will be marked as important in the recipient’s inbox. The priority marks in Gmail are algorithm-determined so you can’t control them.

> ### How importance ranking works
>
> To predict which of your incoming messages are important, Gmail automatically takes into account a number of signals, including:
>
> - **Who you email**: If you email Bob a lot, it’s likely that messages from Bob are important.
> - **Which messages you open**: Messages you open are likely to be more important than those you skip over.
> - **What keywords spark your interest**: If you always read messages about soccer, a new message that contains those same soccer words is more likely to be important.
> - **Which messages you reply to**: If you always reply to messages from your mom, messages she sends are likely to be important.
> - **Your recent use of stars, archive and delete**: Messages you star are probably more important than messages you archive without opening.

See [this help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186543?hl=en) for more details.